# No mounting device after update

Tags: updates

I was updating Ubuntu on my computer, but I didn't have time to wait for it so I restarted my computer, now when I boot it, it says it doesn't have a mounting device. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try booting your system with Live CD and check with GPARTED for all your mounts which are supposed to be there.  To find which are the mounts expected by the system in the startup - view the file /etc/fstab.

Regards
PK